# Force wait/pause until Virtual app launcher instance closes to continue Powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a Powershell script that uses the VAppLauncher program to launch WinSCP three times throughout the code to move files from Windows to Unix.

I was wondering if there is a **command to wait/pause the Powershell script until the virtual WinSCP console is finished and the window closes**. Currently, the code just ploughs through the steps and doesn't wait for this to finish.

The call to the app:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CCM\VAppLauncher.exe /launch "WinSCP 4.0.6.358" /console /script=$aScript /log=$aLog
```

The full code:

```
Try {
    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CCM\VAppLauncher.exe /launch "WinSCP 4.0.6.358" /console /script=$aScript /log=$aLog
}
Catch [Exception] {
    Add-Content $tempLog "$a - System exception running $putScript:"
    Add-Content $tempLog $_.Exception.Message
}
Finally {
    Add-Content $tempLog "$a - WinSCP ran $putScript successfully"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to pipe the instance of WinSCP to Out-Null this will stall the script until WinSCP closes.

```
Try 
{
    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CCM\VAppLauncher.exe /launch "WinSCP 4.0.6.358" /console /script=$aScript /log=$aLog | Out-Null
}
Catch [Exception] 
{
    Add-Content $tempLog "$a - System exception running $putScript:"
    Add-Content $tempLog $_.Exception.Message
}
Finally 
{
    Add-Content $tempLog "$a - WinSCP ran $putScript successfully"
}
```

Notice the `Out-Null` at the end of the try block. You could also use background jobs if you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks will try this out tomorrow

Comment: Sorry about delay. This doesn't seem to work mate. It works in a sense that it pauses the terminal window until the new one is finished but when it returns back to the original terminal window, this script doesn't continue.